# Where to get a Work Contract from a German Company Apostilled?

Tags: germany, brazil

I need to get a Visa for a German worker in Brazil. He is contracted by a German company and is in Brazil for training purpose. We are requesting an RN19 Visa.

"RN19/2017 - to undertake professional training at a Brazilian branch, subsidiary or headquarters of the same economic group (Normative Resolution No. 19/2017);"

For this I need to get his German Work Contract Apostilled, the company is from Berlin. Where can I Apostille his German Work Contract in Berlin? Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

In Berlin there is only one office:

Landesamt für Bürger- und Ordnungsangelegenheiten
Apostillen / Legalisationen

Friedrichstr. 219
10969 Berlin

See link below containing all details what is needed to get this done.

---

**Sources**:

- [Apostille – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostille)

  - no English version available
- [Beglaubigung von Urkunden für das Ausland (Apostille/Legalisation) am Standort Apostillen / Legalisationen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/320315/standort/324291/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mark!

Comment: Do you know the exact address of the authorities that would deal with his case?

Name + Address

Comment: @user19328 The answer contains the address and the link, which should be read.